# What database should I use to save live-streams?

Tags: database, video, video-streaming, live-streaming

My team and I are currently trying to build a live-stream app for windows, the app needs to live-stream and record the live-stream from beginning to end, and then save the live-stream in a database so that it can be viewed later.

Our problems are:
1. What technology should we use to live-stream?
2. How can we save the live-stream for later watch? (What database?)

We thought about live-streaming by sending frame by frame through UDP sockets in C++ (capturing and sending from the server, displaying to the client), but that leads to another problem: How do we turn all of those frames to a video that can be saved and watched later?

P.S. Sorry if I'm not using Stack Overflow correctly, I'm still new to the platform.

Answer (score 0):

No database. Never use databases for bulk storage.

Don’t reinvent the wheel for streaming, use HLS or DASH.

Don’t ask more that one question per stackoverflow post.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How am I supposed the save the streams then?

Comment: Just files on disk, or cloud storage.